# put output from screen command into txt file

Tags: linux, text, command-line, terminal

I am running the command `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` am trying to put its output into a `.txt` file.

I have already tried:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 >> output.txt
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 > output.txt
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 | output.txt
```

But both options didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the manual page for screen command

man screen

-L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using screen to run the command on background, like ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

then you just need to execute like this:

```
ping www.google.com >output.txt 2>&1 &
```